# recursive average word length for a list

Tags: java, average, cpu-word

I try to get the average word length for a List in a recursive way.
So far i get the amount of characters but i still need to divide by `l.size()`.
My problem is that i don´t know where i have to place it. When i place it in the `return` statement, there is a wrong answer.

So far, I have the following:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class RekursivWortlänge {

    public static double avgStringLength(List<String> l) {

        if (l.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        int first = l.get(0).length();

        return first + avgStringLength(l.subList(1, l.size()));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("abc", "abcd", "a", "abcddef");
        double avg = avgStringLength(strings);
        System.out.println(avg);
    }

}
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Where have you tried to put it?  And why hasn't it worked?

Comment: Unless you're forced to use it, recursion isn't the right approach to do this...

Comment: i did it like that: return (first + avgStringLength(l.subList(1, l.size())) / l.size()), and yeah im forced to do it in recusion, its a task for school

Answer (score 0):

It looks like with each of calls you are returning the length of the first string, plus the next call. Wouldn't you have to return the length of the first string / length of array. So:

```
int first = l.get(0).length / l.size();
return first + ...;
```

Then instead of returning

```
3 + ( 4 + ( 1 + ( 7 ) ) )
```

you would be returning:

```
(3/4) + ( (4/4) + ( (1/4) + ( (7/4) ) ) )
```

(extra parenthesis added to help show recursive calls)

Comment: if i do this my answer is 8.0. Isnt he just devide "first" by l.size() and not the rest?

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, Luke's solution above is correct. This would only work if l.size() is consistent across each call. With the code I posted you are adding: (3/4) + (4/3) + (1/2) + (7/1) because the list is getting smaller each time. His solution of holding an original array length solves this. An alternative would be to keep your original solution and divide it by the array length after recursion is over, rather than passing length each time.

Comment: How do i do it when recusion is over? has it to be in a new method or still in the same?

Comment: after this line: `double avg = avgStringLength(strings);`, add a line like: `avg = avg / strings.size()` before your print statement

Comment: Ah yeah ok, but i forgot to say that this is a task for school and the main method has to be excactly like that :/

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, you are returning the summation of the length of each string, when really you want to return the summation of the length of each String divided by the length of the original array.

So what you could do is have the length of the array as a second parameter:

```
public static double avgStringLength(List<String> l, int arrayLength) {

    if (l.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    double first = l.get(0).length();

    return (first/arrayLength) + avgStringLength(l.subList(1, l.size()), arrayLength);

}
```

Note, use a `double` rather than an `int` for the division.

This way, you can call the method like such:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("abc", "abcd", "a", "abcddef");
    double avg = avgStringLength(strings, strings.size());
    System.out.println(avg);
}
```

Which would give the output of 3.75.

Comment: Yeah, thats what i already tried, but this is a task for school, and the main method has to be excactly like mine...

Comment: Is it only the main method which has to be the same? @Marcel